# How can I resolve the argument type error in gesture_detector_builder.dart related to TapDownDetails and TapDragDownDetails in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-dependencies

: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.

- 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
- 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onTapDown: onTapDown,
  ^
  : Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'.
- 'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
- 'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
  ^
  : Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
- 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
- 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
  ^
  : Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'.
- 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
- 'TapDragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
  ^
  : Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
- 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
- 'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
- 'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
  ^
  : Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
- 'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
- 'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
  onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
E/AndroidRuntime(29997): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScreenDecorations
E/AndroidRuntime(29997): Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 29997
E/AndroidRuntime(29997): java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter bottomLeft
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.events.PrivacyDotViewController.initialize(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.setupDecorations(ScreenDecorations.java:315)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.startOnScreenDecorationsThread(ScreenDecorations.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations.$r8$lambda$bRx4s-frKyGv-SmpobluoualBbQ(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at com.android.systemui.ScreenDecorations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(29997):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I wanted to update my application so I just updated the packages along with flutter.After which when I run it, throws the above errors.
Here's my pubspec.yaml packages:
http: ^1.0.0
webfeed: 0.7.0
xml: ^5.4.1
cupertino_icons: 1.0.5
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
share: 2.0.4
launch_review: 3.0.1
url_launcher: ^6.1.11
fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
font_awesome_flutter: 10.4.0
webview_flutter: ^2.3.4
flutter_html: 2.2.1
percent_indicator: 4.2.3
page_indicator: ^0.4.1
admob_flutter: ^3.0.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4

Answer (score 3):

I faced this error after upgrading Flutter to version **3.10.4**.
The issue lies with the **flutter_html** package. It depends on the **flutter_math_fork 0.5.0** which throws the **Gesture_detector** error. Once I replaced the **flutter_html** with a different HTML rendering package the error was resolved

Comment: NO other solution rather to using an alternative?

Comment: Unless the package is updated by the developer

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands on your terminal :

- flutter clean
- fluter pub upgrade
- flutter pub outdated
- flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
- flutter pub get

then run it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, after 2/3 times of `clean` and `get`, it was solved for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue updating flutter version. Flutter html package has now new version just add will solve the issue !

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
```